# Transforming Exceptions thrown from an external library in a centralized way

Tags: java, exception

I would like to ask a code style question around Java Exceptions. I am using Java to call a C/C++ library using JNI. The convention in the library I am using is that most of the methods I can call will throw the same exception type for all errors. Let's call that a LibException. Now LibException is really a wrapper exception for a multitude of errors that can come up ranging from authentication problems, connection problems or more serious problems like corrupt input etc. LibException also contains an error code int as well as the error description string.

Even more confusingly LibException can also wrap one of my own exceptions if I throw it at the library in a callback! What I mean by that is that I sometimes provide a callback method, it is called by the library and I sometimes have to throw an exception in the callback. In that case the library picks up the exception, wraps it up in a LibException and throws it back at me in the original method call.

I would like each of the underlying problem to be handled differently. Authentication problems need to be shown to the user so he can retry, users should be notified of connection problems, but more serious problems may have to trigger my diagnostics report system (an automated mechanism that can send me parts of the logfile for debugging) and of course any exceptions I throw towards the library in the callback need to be rethrown as the original exception type.

Since I am calling different methods at multiple locations, I thought it would be a good idea to put some structure around the exception handling of LibExceptions. This is to avoid code repetition but most importantly to make sure that the different exception types are handled properly and that future me does not forget to, for example, notify the user that authentication failed.

I have tried a bunch of approaches but I am not entirely happy with the code structure I get so I would like some ideas on best practices from the community.

1. Static method that includes logic to sort the exceptions and throw a bunch of other exceptions
   public static void handleException(LibException e) throws AuthenticationException, ConnectionException, SeriousException, MyException     (MyException would be my exception that I throw in the callback)

   - +ve This works well in that it forces the handling of all the thrown exceptions.
   - +ve If a new exception type is added, the compiler would force me to handle the new exception
   - -ve Even though handleException() is a method that always throws an exception, the compiler (rightly) does not know this. This means that if we use handleException() in a method that has to return something, the compiler complains that a return type was missed. To make the compiler happy I have to throw another exception right after calling handleException() so the compiler understands that it will not be getting a return value because an exception is definitely thrown.
   - -ve I don't like the line that looks like Handler.handleException(libEx) since it's not entirely obvious that it throws a bunch of exceptions.
   - -ve Hard to customize the exception messages with context from the location the exception occurred (i.e. which URL we could not connect to).
2. A method that returns an enum with the different types of exceptions that I defined. Based on the enum I can then create the different exceptions to throw.
   public static ExceptionTypeEnum Handler.

   - +ve Since I create the exceptions, I can now customize some error messages with extra context
   - -ve I could still forget to handle an enum (especially if I create a new category in the future)
   - -ve I still need a bunch of custom code to create the exceptions at every place I catch a LibException
3. Similar to #2 but instead of an enum return I could have multiple methods such as isAuthenticationException(libEx) or isConnectionProblem(libEx) and then accordingly throw the exceptions myself.

   - -ve I would definitely forget to handle all sections properly especially if a new exception type is added later.
4. The exception handler could return an exception to throw up. But since we throw a number of different exceptions the getException() method would have to return the Exception base class. This means that exception handlers would have to have prior knowledge of what exceptions could be thrown and also catch the Exception class making my exception handling more difficult.

Now in case I confused everyone with this question, I guess what I am trying to find an elegant solution to is similar to the problem described on section 'Checked exceptions inappropriately expose the implementation details' on page http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html

Does the community have any other suggestions of a coding method to properly and elegantly handle these LibExceptions?